# How to you build a MEX function with Boost Libraries?

Tags: c++, matlab, boost

I'm trying to use the Boost Libraries to write a multi-threaded MEX function. I've installed the Boost Libraries and tested them using Visual Studios. I wrote the following MEX function and tried to build it in the MATLAB console:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

}
```

This was the output

```
>> mex simpleBoostExample.cpp -IC:\Folder\OtherFolder\MATLAB\Files\boost\boost_1_67_0
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017'.
Error using mex
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib'
```

Now I've already added the Boost Library files to the MATLAB PATH like this:

```
path(oldpath, 'C:\Folder\OtherFolder\MATLAB\Files\boost\boost_1_67_0')

setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ';C:\Folder\OtherFolder\MATLAB\Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib']);
```

So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: (Just some addutional info, since you’ve alrwady have a correct answer.) The MATLAB path is only for MATLAB to find functions you call (directories containing M-files and MEX-files), not for header files or libraries or anything related to compiling MEX-files. The `setenv` line is useful only if the directory contains a DLL that is used by a MEX-file. It is not useful for static linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-L` and `-l` to link with dynamic object library *libname* in (optional) *libfolder*.

> -LC:\Folder\OtherFolder\MATLAB\Files\boost\boost_1_67_0 -llibboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib